# String to Date Format

Tags: php, mysql

PHP Mysql i want to convert date format from mysql... please help me.
Like

```
SELECT * FROM agentcommission where AgentId='AC-1363717254' AND Date between STR_TO_DATE('24-Mar-2013','%d-%M-%Y') and R_TOST_DATE('31-Apr-2013','%d-%M-%Y');
```

but it shows Zero rows.
Like
18-Apr-2013 is my date format and i want to convert it to 18-04-2013 Means string to date format

Comment: `R_TOST_DATE` is this a new function?

Comment: Can you show your PHP part of the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [DATE_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function%5Fdate-format) function to convert date from one form to another.

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('24-Mar-2013','%d-%M-%Y'),'%d-%m-%Y');
```

This statement will give you the required formatted date as `24-03-2013`.

But as said above you need a `YYYY-MM-DD` format to use the `BETWEEN` operator to compare dates in your custom date format.

Answer (score 0):

You need `%b` not `%M`

> %b    Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('24-Mar-2013','%d-%b-%Y')
```

Returns

```
March, 24 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

If your `date` column is a `date` type then you need a `YYYY-MM-DD` format. You can't use the `BETWEEN` operator to compare dates in your ***custom*** date format.

Comment: because my all programming is totally depending on that format.